# How to return a struct from a function

Tags: c++, function, struct, return-type

I'm learning c++ and my project is about queues.

I have :

```
struct dough {
    string code;
    int stirringTime;
};
```

Usually in my tasks, we use `int` and not `struct`. That is why I have problems with my delete function:

Using int :

```
int delQ(Queue &Q) // => return int
```

If I make:

```
struct delQ(Queue &Q) // => what do i return?
```

Comment: How would you declare a function returning a int? And now how would you declare the same function but returning another type such as a struct?

Comment: I recommend this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: structs are not functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type that you have defined with `struct` is not `struct` but `dough`.

So if you are use to work with `int`, but want to work with your new structure instead, just replace `int` with `dough`:

```
dough delQ(Queue &Q)  {
    dough retval;   // I don't know how you initialize your struct
    ....
    return retval;  
}
```